# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS won't suspend

Tags: suspend

If I put my computer in suspend mode, it wakes up instantly.

Here's the dmesg output:

```
[532883.492262] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[532883.506700] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[532883.770502] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[532883.786393] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.01 seconds) done.
[532883.802373] PM: Entering mem sleep
[532883.802435] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[532883.802671] hdaps: setting ec_rate=0, filter_order=1
[532883.986749] PM: suspend of drv:psmouse dev:serio2 complete after 184.335 msecs
[532883.987128] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[532883.987179] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[532883.987210] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[532883.988363] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[532884.233649] PM: suspend of drv:tpm_tis dev:00:0a complete after 190.308 msecs
[532884.233804] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: WARN: xHC CMD_RUN timeout
[532884.233816] suspend_common(): xhci_pci_suspend+0x0/0x40 returns -110
[532884.233820] pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -110
[532884.233824] pm_op(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x130 returns -110
[532884.233826] PM: Device 0000:05:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -110
[532884.234927] sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[532884.391729] PM: suspend of drv:sd dev:1:0:0:0 complete after 405.200 msecs
[532884.391840] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
[532884.392158] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[532884.392307] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
[532884.405332] sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: BAR 0: set to [mem 0xf1400000-0xf14000ff] (PCI address [0xf1400000-0xf14000ff])
[532884.405470] sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: restoring config space at offset 0x1 (was 0x100002, writing 0x100006)
[532884.405511] sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[532884.514019] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 121.672 msecs
[532884.514023] PM: resume of drv:usbhid dev:1-1.1:1.0 complete after 121.703 msecs
[532884.514077] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 121.747 msecs
[532884.514100] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:1-1.6:1.1 complete after 121.831 msecs
[532884.514103] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 121.819 msecs
[532884.514118] PM: resume of drv:uvcvideo dev:1-1.6:1.0 complete after 121.879 msecs
[532884.514141] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 121.889 msecs
[532884.881330] PM: resume of drv:sd dev:1:0:0:0 complete after 489.741 msecs
[532884.881380] PM: resume of drv:scsi_disk dev:1:0:0:0 complete after 451.459 msecs
[532884.881416] PM: resume of drv:scsi_device dev:1:0:0:0 complete after 489.817 msecs
[532884.908619] sdhci-pci 0000:0d:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[532884.908738] PM: resume of drv:sdhci-pci dev:0000:0d:00.0 complete after 517.618 msecs
[532884.910009] hdaps: initial mode latch is 0x05
[532884.910148] hdaps: setting ec_rate=250, filter_order=2
[532884.910391] PM: resume of devices complete after 519.320 msecs
[532884.910466] PM: resume devices took 0.520 seconds
[532884.910482] PM: Finishing wakeup.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This just started happening to me yesterday.  Have you had any luck?